# Codeiniter returns empty array for a query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbie to Codeigniter. I'm trying to load some record from a database table. But always returns an empty array.

My codes as follows.

Model - Hottopics_model

```
<?php
class Hottopics_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_hotpost($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('post');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('post', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

}
?>
```

Controller - Hottopics

```
<?php
class Hottopics extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('hottopics_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['hotpost'] = $this->hottopics_model->get_hotpost();

        $this->load->view('hottopics/index', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

View

```
<?php if(!empty($hotpost)){ ?>

<div class="topics-carousel-wrapper">
    <span class="color2">Hot Topics</span>
    <div class="topics-carousel">
        <?php foreach ($hotpost as $row): ?>
            <div class="topic"><a href="single-post.html" title="">
                <?php echo $row->post_title; ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- Hot Topics -->

<?php } ?>
```

Please Help me to solve this matter. Thanks.

Comment: And `post` is the name of your table?

Comment: any PHP *warnings*? ;)

Comment: No need to use this `?>` controllers and models

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside your view:use `$row['post_title']` instead of `$row->post_title` because data is passed in array format.

```
<?php if(!empty($hotpost)){ ?>

<div class="topics-carousel-wrapper">
    <span class="color2">Hot Topics</span>
    <div class="topics-carousel">
        <?php foreach ($hotpost as $row): ?>
            <div class="topic"><a href="single-post.html" title="">
                <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- Hot Topics -->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Still the same problem.